# Dynamic strings.xml file creation from API response

Tags: android, ios, gradle, localization, continuous-integration

I would like to create my strings.xml file dynamically every time I build my project from Android Studio. Right now I'm using [Loco](https://localise.biz/) to share strings across Android and IOS. This tool exposes an API which response is my strings.xml or .strings file (IOS). I would like to know if there is any way to call the API from gradle in order to update the strings files each time the project is build.
Maybe [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) can help me with that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. Basically, with a groovy script in your gradle you can call an http endpoint via `URL` class from `java.net`, get the response of the `GET` call as string and write the response into your string.xml file.

In my build.gradle (Project level) I defined the "`syncStrings`" task as below:

```groovy
task syncStrings {
    def strings = new URL( 'https://localise.biz/api/export/locale/it-IT.xml?format=android&key=<api_key>' ).text
    File file = new File("app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml")
    file.write(strings)
}
```

Hope it helps somebody else ;)